# Как с помощью bash-скрипта проверить, не реплицируется ли база mysql еще куда-то?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

Очень желательно найти способ определения репликации mysql-базы на мастере с наиболее меньшим количеством прав к базе. Нужно учесть, что настройки репликации могут быть различными. Сервера - linux

Comment: *способ определения репликации mysql-базы на мастере с наиболее меньшим количеством прав к базе.* Можно вообще не иметь прав в MySQL. Достаточно иметь право прочитать INI-файл - все настройки репликации находятся в нём.

Comment: какие настройки в ini файле скажут, что репликация действительно работает? Ведь там может быть настроено, но репликация по факту может не работать

Comment: Нужен текущий статус? Тогда нужны права REPLICATION CLIENT и REPLICATION SLAVE. Но наиболее разумно от имени супера (или учётки с указанными выше правами) создать хранимые процедуры, возвращающие информацию о состоянии, с SQL SECURITY DEFINER, тогда тривиально достаточно права EXECUTE на выполнение процедур (вообще, или только этой процедуры).